# Python file not found error after class import in another file

Tags: flask

Ok, i have a python file inside my project with only this class:

```
class hd_XML():
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = 'static/XML/current/'
        self.filename = 'current_settings.xml'
        self.tree = ''

    def open(self):
        self.tree = ET.parse(self.path + self.filename)
        self.root = self.tree.getroot()
        return self.root

    def get_data(self):
        self.root = self.open()
        canale = Channel
        canali = []
        i = 0
        for child in self.root:
            canale.id = child.attrib['id']
            canale.max = child.attrib['max']
            canale.color = child.attrib['color']
            canali.append(canale)
            i += 1
        return canali
```

if i run this class standalone with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    xml = hd_XML()
    print(xml.get_data())
```

that works. But, if I import this class in my main app file as below,

```
import hd_modXML #thats my separate file name

xml = hd_modXML.hd_XML()
canali = xml.get_data()
print(canali[0].id)
```

I cannot retrive the file...

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/XML/current/current_settings.xml'
```

Why?! with a standalone file I can find it and after an import I can't?

project structure:

```
main folder <--- where app.py (where is included hd_modXML.py) and hd_modXML.py are
 |_static
   |_XML
     |_current\ <-- where current_settings.xml is
 |_templates
```

Comment: Can you post the directory structure of your project?

Comment: Please add the directory structure to your post

Comment: just a minute I'm trying to fromat it inside a comment...

Comment: It's difficult to read a directory structure from a comment. Please add it to your original post

Comment: done...hope this helps. It's a typical flask structure

Comment: Are both `app.py` and `hd_modXML.py` in the same folder?

Comment: yes both in the main folder. when the console says that can't find the file it tells me the correct path of file so if i follow the error path i can actually find the file

Comment: I believe the path of the file in `parse` function call takes the absolute path of the file since the `app.py` and `current_settings.xml` are in different locations

Answer (score 0):

After some tries I found that it works giving the parser the whole directory path from root, so in my case:

```
self.path = '/home/grace/pyDev/prova_horus2/static/XML/current/'
```

I don't know why with prievious versions it worked without...

Now I need a way to avoid hardcoding the root path, but for this I can help myself. 
Many thanks to yklsga for pointing me to the right way